# What to do if there is no gym or pokestop?

Tags: pokemon-go

There is no gym and pokestop around me. I have gone so far in search of a gym and pokestop, but I never found one. What should I do now?

Comment: Travel across the land, searching far and wide, each pokemon to understand, the power that's inside.

Comment: are you in a region where the game hasn't been officially released?

Comment: @Rapitor, the game hasn't been officially released in many places, it doesn't prevent people (including myself) from playing in those regions, gyms, pokestops and pokemon spawns are present in those regions.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Niantic support page on Gyms and Pokestops](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221968408):

> Please note, we are currently not accepting submissions for new PokéStops or Gyms.
>
> *If you are having trouble finding PokéStops or Gyms near you, please try visiting a local park or other interesting or historical locations in your community.*

It's possible that in the future they will accept new submissions for new PokéStops or Gyms, so you should stay tuned and follow any developments on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://pokemongohub.net/post/breaking-news/brazilian-player-manages-get-30-new-pokestops-contacting-niantic-support/) details a player who had success getting pokestops added by reporting it as a bug to Niantic support since there were Ingress portals but no pokestops.

Answer (score 1):

Though slightly anecdotal, I have found the game client to be extremely buggy.

It frequently seems to stop updating data from the server, and will refuse to render Pokéstops or Gyms until it has been force-closed and relaunched.

It may be worth trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, at the moment, you don't have much of a choice. If feasible, you may wish to travel a little further and see if there are any Pokéstops or Gyms there. Otherwise, you will simply have to wait until Niantic open up for suggesting Gyms and Pokéstops so you can suggest a few in the area where you live if none have been added by then.